# How does dev_t hold more than 1 minor numbers?

Tags: linux-device-driver

If the below api reserves 3 devices (2,3,4) under a randomly selected major number, where is the minor number 3 and 4 stored in dev_t variable dev_no?

```
alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_no, 2,3, "mod3-device");
```

when the minor number is extracted using the MINOR(dev_t) macro, I could get only 1 minor number(i.e., 2).

```
me@myPC:~/work/dd/2018$ dmesg | tail
[16577.759505] module_init()
[17301.433970] major:minor 238:2
```

I read that in a dev_t variable, 20 bits are reserved for minor number and 12 bits for major number though the range for both minor and major numbers is 0-255. yet I didn't get a clear picture as on how the major:minor numbers are stored for the /dev/devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understanding of alloc_chrdev_region is wrong.

When you ask it to 'reserve' for you 3 minor numbers starting from 2, It means that it **Reserves** it for you and the dev_no is only filler with the combination of Major number and first minor number.

Reserved means that when you try to use the same Major number for more Minor numbers, the new minor numbers will start from 5 i.e 2,3, and 4 are reserved.